# VBA code to update links in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me on this? I have an excel file where I want to write a code that picks a value from a specific cell from the same workbook and paste it into another workbook. I am not sure how can I connect two workbooks and update the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use queries for this.

If you specifically want to do this with VBA, you can open another workbook using:

```
Dim Tr As Workbook
Set Tr = Workbooks.Open(TFileName)
```

where `TFileName` stands for the full path of your second workbook. If you set your second workbook you can copy paste anything you want.

You can also use this:

```
Tr.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

so the workbook stays in the background